# Extended WPF Toolkit Datagrid with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpftoolkit

Sorry but I only found the way with the FieldName defined in the column tag or the old style

```
<xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsMetals" Source="{Binding MetalTypes}">
    <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <!--<PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Year" />-->
    </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>

<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsMetals} }" AutoCreateColumns="True">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" IsMainColumn="True"></xcdg:Column>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Year"></xcdg:Column>    
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="SelectedMetalSeries.Name"></xcdg:Column>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>

</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

The last column with **SelectedMetalSeries.Name** is a class with properties. I didn't find a way to show this property name of the object

My ViewModels:

```
public class AllMetalTypeViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MetalTypeViewModel> _metalTypes;
    public ObservableCollection<MetalTypeViewModel> MetalTypes
    {
        get { return _metalTypes; }
        set { Set("MetalTypes", ref _metalTypes, value); }
    }
```

---

```
public class MetalTypeViewModel: WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private MetalSeries _selectedMetalSeries;
    public MetalSeries SelectedMetalSeries
    {
        get { return _selectedMetalSeries; }
        set { Set("SelectedMetalSeries", ref _selectedMetalSeries, value); }
    }

    private short _year;
    public short Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set { Set("Year", ref _year, value); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { Set("Name", ref _name, value); }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class MetalSeries
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual long ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I found the old style which seems no longer to work with the new version:

```
<ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Publisher" Binding="{Binding Publisher}" AllowAutoFilter="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="*"/>
```

The problem is that I can't find a property where I can bind my ViewModel properties

[DataGrid Version 1.9.0](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Hmm...without knowing the data source...What's the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGridControl`? What does the underlying VM look like?

Comment: I've added the classes

Answer (score 1):

It is a FieldName not Binding and as I see it does not support nesting. However a "good" design should not have such issues. I would try simply creating a dedicated ViewModel for the DataGrid.